# Linux Bash script: stat perm and shortname

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

I need to print permission and just the name on a list of files.

I am already in this point, but I don't know what else can I do:

```
find /Home/PathA/PathB/.../PathN/*170719*.txt -exec stat -c "%a %n" -printf %f\\n\\r {} \;
```

I am pretty sure that the `-print` argument is the problem.

I need this on the results;

```
777 fileA170719.txt
640 fileB170719_errors.txt
```

Can a good soul out there help me to improve this?

Comment: get your `stat` cmd to work for one file (from the cmd-line). Then you can think about any extra quoting that may be required to run from `find .. -exec` . `find ... | xargs stat ...` maybe a better approach.

Comment: Be also you a good soul. *Never write "I" in lowercase.* [Similar suggestions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370)